# Django return JsonResponse and continue

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have this function in Django and I want that when ever the  return JsonResponse(payload) is executed, Django should continue to execute the rest of the code but the rest of the code is rather not

```
def paytes(request): 
        payload ={
                "USERID": code_id,
                "MSISDN": serviceCode,
                "MSGTYPE": type_msg,
                "USERDATA": text,
                "SESSIONID": session_id,
                "MSG": response,
            }
        print('MSG: ',response)
        # headers = {
        #     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        # }
        # response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
        return JsonResponse(payload)
        url = 'https://prod.theteller.net/v1.1/transaction/process'
        transaction_id = random.randint(100000000000, 999999999999)
        amounte = "000000000080"
        amount = str(amounte)
        data = {
            "amount" :amount,
            "processing_code" : "000200",
            "transaction_id" : transaction_id,
            "desc" : "Mobile Money Payment Test",
            "merchant_id" : "TTM-00000727",
            "subscriber_number" : "233244491909",
            "r-switch" : "MTN",
            }
        encoded = base64.b64encode(b'rad5d4a81d6a3453:MTQwODBiMjU3Yzg1ODhhYmIwM2Q5ZmFmYWVlNjJkOWQ=') # change this as well
        headers =  {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded.decode("utf-8")}',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
        res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        print(res.text)
        response_data = res.json()
        status = response_data["status"]
        print(response_data)
        print(status)
        return HttpResponse(res)
```

Comment: You know Python, right? You know that `return` ends executing function and returns what is given after that command in the same line, right?

Answer (score 0):

All the code after the first return statement is executed won't be executed, so if you want to return both of those variables then put them inside the same dictionary and return that:

```
return_val = {}
return_val['payload'] = payload
return_val['response'] = res
return JsonResponse(return_val)
```